# Result appear for a moment and then disappeared

Tags: javascript, html

> This script should return result and displayed result in "answer" >paragraph
>   but instead it appears for moment and then
>   disappeared, what i miss?

```js
< script >

  function dataValidation() {
    var initial = document.getElementById("anyWord").value
    var char = /[^а-яА-Я]/


    if (initial == null || initial == "") {
      alert('Please, enter only cyrillic letters.')
    } else if (initial.match(char)) {
      alert('Please enter only cyrillic')
    } else shmovoConverter()
  }

function shmovoConverter() {
  var sAnyWord = document.getElementById('anyWord').value
  var shm = 'Шм'
  var vowels = ['а', 'у', 'о', 'ы', 'и', 'э', 'я', 'ю', 'ё', 'е', 'а', 'у']
  var consonants = ['б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'ж', 'з', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ']


  for (var i = 0; i < vowels.length; i++) {
    var firstLater = sAnyWord.substring(0, 1)
    if (firstLater === vowels[i]) {
      alert(shm + sAnyWord)
      var sAnswer = shm + sAnyWord
      document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = sAnswer

    } else {
      for (var j = 0; j < consonants.length; j++) {
        if (firstLater === consonants[j]) {
          sAnyWord = sAnyWord.substring(1, sAnyWord.length)
          i = 0
        }
      }
    }
  }


}




< /script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Registration Form</title>

</head>


<body style="background-color: #FFFFCC">
  <div style="margin-left: 200px;
margin-top: 100px;
margin-bottom: auto;
margin-right: 400px;
border: solid;
border-color: #D6BA01;
background-color: #F5DEB3">
    <form id="RegForm">
      <p style="margin-left: 10px" align="center">Slovo - Shmovo</p>
      <p style="margin-left: 10px">Enter any word:
        <input type="text" id="anyWord">
      </p>
      <p></p>
      <p style="margin-left: 10px">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submitBtn" onclick="dataValidation()" />
      </p>
      <p id="answer"></p>
    </form>
```

This script should return result and displayed result in "answer" paragraph, but instead it appears for moment and then disappeared, what i miss?

Comment: Return false at the end of dataValidation function

Answer (score 0):

If the result shows (in your code provided it does not), the problem here is that you have submit(there is no handler for that, just the page is refreshed), change the type to "button" not "submit" or replace with button element

Answer (score 0):

the problem that when you press the button the form submit and the page is loaded 
you can solve that by one way:-

1- make the form tag `<form id="RegForm" action="#">`

2- make your button onclick return false like this `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submitBtn" onclick="dataValidation();return false;" />`

that will solve your problem